# Signing / Verifying HTTPS Responses

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

Is it possible to verify that a response originated from a website?

For example, it's trivially easy to forge a screenshot of a website - I can make it look like a politician Tweeted something awful.

Twitter's website is protected with HTTPS - that means that responses are encrypted. Are they also signed?

Is it possible to get a signed HTTPS response out of a server so that I can prove / verify that it served that data?

For example, can I `wget` or `curl` https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/645299508897714176 and get back back a response which I can use to prove that Twitter served this content?

(I can't see anything relevant with `wget -S` or `curl -iv --raw`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to software development and more of a conceptional question. [security.se] might be better suited for this type of question. If you re-ask the question, make sure to describe how you envision the communication architecture.

Answer (score 1):

An https response **is** signed. Unless you ask them not to, curl and wget do verify the certificate chain. That chain must end but a certificate of an authority that your computer trust. That authority certify that the certificate is valid, and wget/curl has verify that the certificate correspond to the domain name. Thus, only the owner of the private key of that certificate can encrypt/decrypt the data.

With "curl -v " you can see more informations about the tls authentication.