# Saving HTTPS session dump as an evidence

Tags: https

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695108/signing-verifying-https-responses).

Usecase 1: a site hosts message and uses HTTPS. I want to dump the HTTPS session traffic to be able to substantially claim later that that the site did provide the message even if website does not have it anymore.

Question 1: is it possible to do so? If yes, what are practical ways of doing it?

---

Now, if only it is possible...

Usecase 2: somebody dumps HTTPS session and then wants to substitute the website respose with another response from same website (or signed with same certificate) so that the HTTPS session dump looks valid.

Question 2: is it possible?

P.S. Will it suit Security.SE better?

Comment: [Found an extual example](https://tlsnotary.org/). Question 2 remains open.